# How do I enable multiple client ids in a Spring Boot OAuth2 Server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have Spring Boot OAuth2 server working, but now we need to distinguish between different clients from different departments and provide different functionality depending on the department. I figure I can separate it by the client id. This guide shows how to set up the OAuth2 server with a single client id, but how do I set it up with multiple client ids?

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_social_login_authserver

And then, when an API request is made, how do I find out which client id it is?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What you need is dynamic client registration as shown here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-dynamic-client-registration

Comment: I set up 2 static clients. Can I do that? `clients.jdbc(dataSource).withClient(applicationName)....and().withClient(applicationName+"-sales")`

Comment: No, I am unable to do that. It requires `oauth_client_details` table and will attempt to insert two rows into the database, and the next time it runs, it will attempt to re-insert them, causing a duplicate key violation. Who knew it would insert client ids into the DB? I thought it would just store them (client id/secret) in memory, but store the tokens in the DB. And I inject `java.security.Principal` into the request signature and I then have the client id of the request.

Comment: I can't understand why this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple entries in table **oauth_client_details** with different combination of client_id and client_secret. The client_secret obviously will be encrypted.

Now to generate the refresh and access token, hit the url 
`/oauth/token` with `Authorization : Basic base64-encoded`,

Where base64-encoded will be Base64 encryption of `client_id:client_secret`. 
Remember, client_secret here should be original plain password (without encryption).

The same thing can be achieved using Spring xml configuration (in older way) as

```
<oauth:client client-id="mobile_ios"
        authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,implicit" secret="ios_s3cret"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" 
        refresh-token-validity="7776000"
        access-token-validity="300" />

    <oauth:client client-id="mobile_android"
        authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,implicit" secret="android_s3cret"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        refresh-token-validity="7776000"
        access-token-validity="300" />

    <oauth:client client-id="web_app"
        authorized-grant-types="password,refresh_token,implicit" secret="web_s3cret"
        authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" 
        refresh-token-validity="7776000"
        access-token-validity="30000" />
</oauth:client-details-service>
```